# Lightbox Next/Previous Buttons missing?

Tags: php, gallery, lightbox

I built a dynamic gallery with html and PHP and I'm using Lightbox to display the images. Everything functions but when i click an image the next and previous buttons are missing and the only way to cycle through images is to close the current open image and open another one.

I found the dynamic implementation here: http://www.fatbellyman.com/webstuff/lightbox_gallery/

This is my code as of yet:

```
<?php

    function lightbox_display($dir_to_search, $rel){
            $image_dir = $dir_to_search;
            $dir_to_search = scandir($dir_to_search);
            $image_exts = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
            $excluded_filename = '_t';
                    foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
                    $dot = strrpos($image_file, '.');
                    $filename = substr($image_file, 0, $dot);
                    $filetype = substr($image_file, $dot+1);
                    $thumbnail_file = strrpos($filename, $excluded_filename);
                            if ((!$thumbnail_file) and array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false){echo "<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."'data-lightbox='".$image_dir.$image_file."' rel='".$rel."'>
              <img src='".$image_dir.$filename."_t.".$filetype."' alt='".$filename."' width='100' height='80' title=''/></a>"."\n";}}}
?>
```

This is where I add the gallery to my HTML page:

```
<?php lightbox_display('img/gallery/', 'My_Gallery'); ?>
```

Comment: More related to css/html issue, not php...

Answer (score 0):

If I would have waited 10 more minutes before posting... lol

I changed

```
<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."'data-lightbox='".$image_dir.$image_file."' rel='".$rel."'>
```

into

```
<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."'data-lightbox='my_gallery' rel='".$rel."'>
```

I am guessing this added them all to one "show"